# SVG in mPDF (PHP library )

Tags: php, pdf, svg, fpdf

In php code I use **mPDF** library for generating PDF.
I am facing a problem with insert svg into PDF
The svg file I catch via POST:

```
   $svg = $_POST['structureSVG'];
   $svg_pdf = str_replace('"', '\'', $svg); //change " to '
```

proof what is inside:

```
   var_dump($svg_pdf);
    //shows string which contains: 
<svg>...</svg>
```

here I can be sure, that the SVG was captured correctly. So I put the SVG:

```
$html = " <div> $svg_pdf </div> ";
$mpdf -> WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf -> Output('pdf/test_svg.pdf', 'I');
```

but unfortunately the SVG picture is not rendered in PDF

thank You for any help

Comment: Have you read the mPDF manual specifically related to what is and not support in SVG? http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=245 No one can guess about your specifc SVG and you should read all of this and examine your SVG and see whether it is supported

Comment: Yes I have read the manual and for make me sure I have made simply svg contained just one element <rect> and in same way I have tried to insert into my code, but the result was same

Comment: I would like to communicate on mPDF forum, but there is not possible register account. Do anybody account on the mPDF forum?

Answer (score 4):

You need to handle the SVG as regular `<img>` tag. From my point of view, it'd be easiest to save the file to the temp directory and then let it load with mPDF:

`<img src="path/to/the/temp/file.svg">`

Unfortunately, you can not use data uri for SVG images (at least in version 5.7.4).

Comment: thank You, but I have stop use mPDF, because there is one problem unsolvable...when SVG contains a few layers with parameter 'diplay:none' mPDF doesn't respect such parameter

Comment: Single Layer SVG is working properly with th mpdf library, but when there are multiple layers, it will not work properly. It is best way to use other libraries i.e. TCPDF, wkhtmltopdf etc..

Comment: This saved me a lot of time. Thank you!